# Internal Error: Metro Bundler has encountered an internal error [Duplicate Module]

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, react-native, node-modules

**The ERROR I see is this:**

[image: This is the error I see]

I SAW A LOT OF QUESTIONS REGARDING THIS ERROR BUT ALL WERE OF SOME DIFFERENT CONTEXT. I see that this error has to be something relating to name collisions in `node_modules`. ***NOT DUPLICATE***

---

MetroBundler in terminal:

```
Loading dependency graph...(node:739) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: 
jest-haste-map: @providesModule naming collision:
  Duplicate module name: react-native
  Paths: /Users/iqubex/Sites/FidoDido/node_modules/react-native/package.json collides with /Users/iqubex/Sites/FidoDido/node_modules/iconic-input/node_modules/react-native/package.json

This error is caused by a @providesModule declaration with the same name across two different files.
    at setModule (/Users/iqubex/Sites/FidoDido/node_modules/react-native/node_modules/jest-haste-map/build/index.js:462:17)
    at workerReply (/Users/iqubex/Sites/FidoDido/node_modules/react-native/node_modules/jest-haste-map/build/index.js:512:9)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)
(node:739) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 2)
(node:739) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
::ffff:127.0.0.1 - - [29/Sep/2018:08:40:16 +0000] "GET /onchange HTTP/1.1" - - "-" "okhttp/3.10.0"
```

---

**This is my `package.json`:**

```
{
  "name": "fidodido",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node node_modules/react-native/local-cli/cli.js start",
    "test": "jest"
  },
  "rnpm": {
    "assets": [
      "./app/assets/fonts/"
    ]
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "array-includes": "^3.0.3",
    "corejs": "^1.0.0",
    "es6-symbol": "^3.1.1",
    "firebase": "^5.4.0",
    "iconic-input": "^1.0.2",
    "native-base": "^2.7.2",
    "react": "16.4.1",
    "react-native": "^0.57.1",
    "react-navigation": "^2.11.2",
    "rn-sliding-up-panel": "^1.2.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-jest": "23.4.2",
    "babel-preset-react-native": "^5",
    "jest": "23.5.0",
    "react-test-renderer": "16.4.1"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "react-native"
  }
}
```

---

Node version: `v10.8.0`
npm version: `v6.2.0`
OS: Android (Developing on Mac)

I am seriously unaware of what's happening around. Looks like all broken and not working. **PLEASE HELP!**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem seems to be that the [ionic-input package.json](https://github.com/KumarAbhirup/iconic-input/blob/v1.0.0/package.json) file list react-native as a dependency instead of listing it as devDependency like all of other react-native related package.

Since ionic-input is relatively new I guess this deserves an issue on his repo.

Anyway I guess a quick workaround would be to edit yourself the /node_modules/ionic-input/package.json to put react-native as a devDependency

Can you try to change this (/node_modules/ionic-input/package.json) :

```
{
  "name": "iconic-input",
  "version": "1.0.3",
  "description": "Beautiful Input components for React Native",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
        "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "repository": {
        "type": "git",
        "url": "https://www.github.com/KumarAbhirup/iconic-input"
  },
  "keywords": [
    "React",
    "React",
    "Native",
    "Javascript",
    "Node.js",
    "Component"
  ],
  "author": "Kumar Abhirup",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "native-base": "^2.7.2",
    "react": "^16.4.2",
    "react-native": "^0.56.0"
  }
}
```

into this :

```
{
  "name": "iconic-input",
  "version": "1.0.3",
  "description": "Beautiful Input components for React Native",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
        "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "repository": {
        "type": "git",
        "url": "https://www.github.com/KumarAbhirup/iconic-input"
  },
  "keywords": [
    "React",
    "React",
    "Native",
    "Javascript",
    "Node.js",
    "Component"
  ],
  "author": "Kumar Abhirup",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "native-base": "^2.7.2",
    "react": "^16.4.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "react-native": "^0.56.0"
  }

}
```

Comment: thanks a lot. how should I do that? I am actually new. So can you edit the answer and show what change to make in package.json?

Comment: when you do that, can you then remove the node_modules file found at YOUR_PROJECT/node_modules/ionic-input/node_modules then cd into that directory and run npm install ?

Comment: sure will do then, wait please

Comment: `error: bundling failed: Error: jest-haste-map: @providesModule naming collision:
  Duplicate module name: react-native
  Paths: /Users/iqubex/Sites/FidoDido/node_modules/react-native/package.json collides with /Users/iqubex/Sites/FidoDido/node_modules/iconic-input/node_modules/react-native/package.json`

Comment: can you try to Reset the packager cache: `rm -fr $TMPDIR/react-*` or `npm start --reset-cache`. ?

Comment: `Error: Cannot find module '@babel/core'`

Comment: I'll be glad if you could also see this :-)

Comment: hmm I actually do not think I deserve this upvote since I am not really sure that did the trick... anyway create another question for the @babel/core problem in order to keep things readable and understandable :)